# Images coming through as text/html, not png

Tags: image, vuejs3, vuetify.js, png

I'm trying to get v-carousel to show an array of local images.

In my code, you can see I've tried several ways to access the images locally. Nothing shows.

I noticed in the devtools, that the files were coming through as text/html, yet they are saved in my local as PNGs. From what I can tell on my own research, there is some setting some where that needs to be changed??

Any ideas as to why this is the case?

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-carousel>
      <v-carousel-item
        v-for="(photo, i) in photos"
        :key="i"
        :src="photo.src"
      ></v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'RotatingPhotos.vue',
  data() {
    return {
      photos: [
        {
          src: '../src/assets/latte.png',
        },
        {
          src: './src/assets/icedtea.png',
        },
        {
          src: '@/src/assets/mocha.png',
        },
        {
          src: 'src/assets/brunch.png',
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the text/html designation was not the issue.

I had to use the require method.

```
photos: [
        // Images wouldn't render unless I use the require method
        {
          src: require('@/assets/latte.png'),
        },
        {
          src: require('@/assets/icedtea.png'),
        },
        {
          src: require('@/assets/mocha.png'),
        },
        {
          src: require('@/assets/brunch.png'),
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

the code where using src attribute in the vuetify.js is there: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VImg/VImg.ts#L110
so, it use `background-image: url()` in css, the path based on css file.

then please refer to [background-image URL not loading using Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49018561/background-image-url-not-loading-using-webpack)